# What is $\left\lfloor0.\overline{9}\right\rfloor$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, decimal-expansion

We know that $0.\overline{9} = 1$ but then what is $\left\lfloor0.\overline{9}\right\rfloor$?

My thought process went:
$0.\overline{9} = 1$ so therefore $\left\lfloor0.\overline{9}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor1\right\rfloor$

But also $\left\lfloor0.9\right\rfloor = 0$ and it shouldn't change no matter how many numbers you add on to the back of it.

So what is the right answer, if there is one, and why?

Comment: Well, $\lfloor \,\cdot\,\rfloor$ is not continuous at integers.

Comment: You have to ascribe a meaning to $\lfloor 0.\bar{9}\rfloor$ before you can even give an intelligible answer to this. Do you do the floor before evaluating the limit? Or do you evaluate the floor and then do the limit? The floor function is not continuous so it matters in which order you do things (you can't push limits around as this example shows).

Comment: What is the square root of 49?  At first I thought it was 7, but then I realized that the square root of 4 is 2, and it shouldn't change no matter how many numbers you add on to the back of it.  So now I think the square root of 49 is 2.  So which is the right answer?

Comment: Your third point is an attempt at induction on the number of decimal places, so it need not apply in the limit.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ??? There's nothing ambiguous about the notation. $0.\overline 9$ denotes a certain limit, so the whatsis in the question is the floor of the limit.

Comment: @David I'm with you but OP clearly doesn't understand the notation which is why I said what I did.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah, on a second reading I think I just ascribed an incorrect meaning to the words "ascribe a meaning to" - I took that as saying he got to decide which interpretation to use, but no, you didn't actually say that. Sorry

Answer (score 14):

As you say, $0.\overline9=1$. Thus, $0.\overline9$, like $2-1$, $\frac33$, etc., is just a different notation for the number $1$, and consequently $\left\lfloor0.\overline9\right\rfloor=\lfloor1\rfloor=1$.

**Added:** The fact that $\lfloor 0.9\ldots9\rfloor=0$ for any finite string of $9$s is irrelevant: the floor function is not continuous from the left at integers. In effect you’re saying that $\lfloor 1\rfloor$ ought to be $0$ simply because $\left\lfloor 1-10^{-n}\right\rfloor=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: I don’t suppose that the downvoter would care to explain what’s wrong?

Comment: Nice Brian... Vote up!

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> But also $\left\lfloor0.9\right\rfloor = 0$ and it shouldn't change no matter how many numbers you add on to the back of it.

That is a common mistake when dealing with repeating decimals, one tends to think, that you just add more and more $9$'s and get closer and closer to $1$. In my oppinion, this is because we normally think only in some "finite sense". To a certain degree, everything in our everyday world is finite, so it might be difficult, to think of $0.\overline{9}$ as really infinite many $9$'s. The representation $0.999\dots$ does not help either, as there are only a finite number of $9$'s displayed.

So: for $\lfloor 0.9\rfloor=0$ it does not matter, if you add "some $9$'s" on to the back of it, but once you get to $0.\overline{9}$, it does matter.

Answer (score -2):

To me the intuitive explanation is that if you put any *number* of 9s after the 0, $\lfloor 0.999...99 \rfloor =0$. But $0.\overline{9}$ has infinite 9s after the 0, and infinity isn't a number. So the pattern doesn't hold.

Cameron Williams pointed out the rigorous answer, which is that you're implicitly assuming that because a sequence of numbers (0.9,0.99,0.999...) gets closer to 1, then if you apply a function to them (in this case, $\lfloor x \rfloor$), the the resulting sequence ($\lfloor 0.9\rfloor$,$\lfloor 0.99\rfloor$,$\lfloor 0.999\rfloor$...) should also get closer to  $\lfloor 1\rfloor$. But functions don't always do this. If a certain function does have this property, we say that the function is continuous at that point, but $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is not continuous at 1. In fact, you've more or less given a proof that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is discontinuous at 1.

Comment: That is literally what I just said.

Comment: @AAron Not really, continuity is indeed at the heart of this question (also mentioned by Daniel Fischer early on in the comments).  It's fallacious to think that every property (in this case "rounds down to $0$") passes through to the limit in every case.

Comment: @AAron You've deleted the answer, but in it you said $0.\overline{9}$ isn't a number, which this answer doesn't claim.

Comment: I misinterpreted numbers altogether for a bit. A brain fart. All your disproofs of numbers are true and I am wrong